# Inexpensive CFML hosting on servers in EU

Tags: coldfusion, shared-hosting, railo, openbd

I'd like to change shared-hosting from servers located in US to EU in order to decrease number of hops and latency.

Anyone having first hand experience with Coldfusion/Railo/OBD hosting providers from Europe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend to check out Centinated in Switzerland [http://www.centinated.ch](http://www.centinated.ch/en/index.cfm/treeID/74) They are specialized in ColdFusion Hosting (shared and dedicated) and there is an offer for resellers, too.

If you prefer dedicated Servers and want to have your own ColdFusion or Railo install, Serverloft http://www.serverloft.eu/ always has very competitive offers. Servers are located in Frankfurt/Germany or St. Louis/USA.

Answer (score 1):

And now something completely different, these guys are giving it for free, check them out http://www.hostmediauk.com/railo-hosting/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know your meaning of "inexpensive", but following solution should match: Linode.com VPS in London + self-installed Railo (my choise is Ubuntu Server + Apache2 + Resin + Railo).

Comment: "Inexpensive" like same/similar price as servers in US where you can take decent shared-hosting plan starting at ~100EUR/year (http://www.hostmediauk.com/railo-hosting/, https://alurium.com/clients/cart.php?gid=1 )